# How to tap on a android app button that is not visible because of a small screen?

Tags: android, input, touch, simulation, tap

I completed the most steps of connecting procedure of inapp wizard. Most of the steps were scrollable but at the end of wizard last step was to hit a text button which writes Connect on it, but I cant scroll that page down and couldn't see that button as same as on the phone ui. It's a text base button according to me because when I try to  resize the app window same with my watch screen on my phone, the text letters start to separate and form changes to vertical. But when I completely downsize window to same with watch's size button completely disappears and cant tap on it.

So is there a command to tap this invisible button by a button id or the text label over interactive shell session?

---

I researched some possible actions by reasoning with my tiny knowledge and tried

```
getevent -l command
```

Print all touches to screen top and bottom points
Converted the xy coordinates hex to decimal
Tried input tap command to touch possible imaginary pixels below the screen eg: the bottom of screen is 701px so i think the distance between the top visible text which starts with ''we found the following Melitta..'' and the invisible connect button is about x2 a watch screen so I tried

```
input tap 343 1200,1300,1400,1500...
```

But it did not work because there is not a pixel coordinate on the watch's screen. So this beings me to second step to found a way to select exact word ''Connect'' button by a command

I'm looking for a command like

```
input tap text<Command>
```

or something like that.

Comment: Normally its visible on phone you can check the phone screenshot but cant seen on samsung watch4 screen when sideloaded

Comment: it may be easier to determine how the appliance is controlled and then write a program to control it

Comment: It may be only harder for me. I m a regular person. If i can just tap on that button once its ok for me. for the future connects appliance autorizes the devices connected to it.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. That said, if you are sideloading / using adb you might be able to use [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) to control your watch from a PC and use the keyboard to get widget focus for your 'Connect' button.

Comment: I started adb over my phone. Actually i do not have a physical keyboard but tried remote desktoping it and used a screen keyboard as same on a regular pc it has tab ctrl and arrow keys on it. and arrow keys didnt work on that stage of app this was an intermediate level idea which i tried before think i am asking a command which can be used in android programming. So rather than saying stackflow is this stackflow is that some knowledge based help is much appreciated. I am asking a command type and commands regularly used in programming isnt it

Comment: Is there any capturing app logs the processes we have tap meaby i can learn the button id on phone when i tap on that connect button

Answer (score 0):

Hi to all thanks for answers i solved my issue by a simple way i edited the apk over apk parser pto app on my phone and deleted the unneccessary warning texts on that last page after that compile it back and build a mod apk by this way device connect button come up and i able to tap it and connected to device.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwirB.jpg)